# Textfield background color not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c

New to iOS Obj C and I have a requirement to change background color of text field.

I have tableview which is like below

Screen 1:

1. Enter Employee ID: (Text Field Here)
2. Select Department  --> On tapping this , goes to another screen (Screen 2) to display list of departments

Once a department has selected screen 1 will be displayed.

I want to change background color of  Textfiled (Enter ID) upon entering valid id.

I did it in textFieldDidEndEditing method like 
 textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

STEPS:
1. Entered valid employee id :: background color changed to green (as expected)
2.  when i tap department and select a department,  screen 1 appears and my background color which I set to green for employee id is no longer shown. It clears the color.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the code that you have try?, it will be helpful us to understand.

Comment: How you are showing the screen 1 ? Are you presenting a new instance of screen 1 or are you just popping the scrren 2 ?

Comment: Just popping screen 2. I have all the values coming from Plist file

Comment: Nirav, as of now i have added  textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; to method textFieldDidEndEditing

Comment: Have you set `backgroundColor` of textField in `viewDidAppear` check that it may cause issue.

Comment: As Nirav suggested, the problem is that the view is reloaded when you get back from Screen 2.  Most likely you are setting the textfield's background color to clear in viewDidAppear, another option is that the view is reloaded when you get back from screen 2, therefore loading an entirely different textfield.  You will need to share the details of the view hierarchy of Screen 1 and Screen 2 (is it pushed, presented modally, etc.) and we will need to know if you ever set the textfield's background color to anything besides green, and if so where.

Comment: These are actually XIB files. Within my screen 1, for textfield we have implemented custom cell class file which doesn't have viewdidAppear. However in my screen1 as well no viewDidAppear setting background color. I have set clear color in my text cell custom class file in method textFieldDidBeginEditing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said your textField is in textview. Now, first give tag to you textfield try to work with textfield tags, see,

```
//celforRow
objCell.textField.tag =  indexPath.row;
```

in TextField:DidEnd

```
 if(sender.tag == 0)// i.e. TextField for emploee ID
    {
    bool check = [self validateEmplee];// check Validation returns true if valid otherwise returns no.
       if(check){ // if valid
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
else{
   sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
    }
```